# I couldn't start 'Hive' even after Name Node Safe mode

Tags: hadoop, hive

However Hadoop multinode is working fine with

```
[acadgild@localhost ~]$ jps
3378 NodeManager
2841 NameNode
3131 SecondaryNameNode
3835 Jps
3276 ResourceManager
2942 DataNode
```

But when I run

```
[acadgild@localhost ~]$ hive
```

It shows following errors:

```
/usr/local/hive/bin/hive-config.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/hive/bin/hive-config.sh: line 1: `# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more'
^C
[acadgild@localhost ~]$ hive
/usr/local/hive/bin/hive-config.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/hive/bin/hive-config.sh: line 1: `# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more'

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-0.14.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot create directory /tmp/hive/acadgild/709e943f-3ca4-4b81-a7fb-e5d1a8c68baf. Name node is in safe mode.
Resources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually. NOTE:  If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode. Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn safe mode off.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkNameNodeSafeMode(FSNamesystem.java:1364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:4216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:4191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:813)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:672)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot create directory /tmp/hive/acadgild/709e943f-3ca4-4b81-a7fb-e5d1a8c68baf. Name node is in safe mode.
Resources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually. NOTE:  If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode. Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn safe mode off.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkNameNodeSafeMode(FSNamesystem.java:1364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:4216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:4191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:813)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:539)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2753)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2724)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:870)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:859)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createPath(SessionState.java:556)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:430)
        ... 8 more
```

After getting this error, I hit below command

```
[acadgild@localhost ~]$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
17/09/25 13:04:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Safe mode is OFF
```

And Again tried
`[acadgild@localhost ~`]$ hive

But getting the same error and couldnt open Hive promt.. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Name node is in safe mode" means not enough datanodes have reported in
with the block reports. Visit the Namenode UI to find out which datanodes
have not reported in yet.

Alternatively one or more datanodes have lost blocks from their local
filesystem. You can run the

```
"sudo -u hdfs hdfs fsck / -listcourruptblocks"
```

command to see which files are corrupt

Reference: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Error-while-starting-Hive/m-p/32321#M5587

Comment: I ran given command but getting below error

**[acadgild@localhost ~]$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs fsck / -listcourruptblocks

sudo: unknown user: hdfs

sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin**

Comment: The first hdfs after sudo is the HDFS Service user. Replace that with whatever name you chose. I hope that works for you!